# Filter Visual Studio 2008's "Members" drop-down box

Tags: visual-studio-2008, filter

Myself, along with my coworkers, aren't aware of any way to filter what is show in the "Members" drop-down box in Visual Studio.  This is the drop-down box that lets you jump to different methods and functions depending on where you're at inside your project.

I find it very useful, but it'd be nice to not show a bunch of items I'll never use; such is the case with displaying all of the labels I've created on a Windows form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't plan to reference a label anywhere in your code, you can change the GenerateMember property to false from the designer.  This will create the label locally within the InitializeComponent method - and will no longer show up in your list.

Comment: +1 - So that's what that property does! lol! i've ignored it for years. Thanks for the good tip Pedro.